# Integrated development environment setup for Flutter

Tags: flutter

I'm beginning to learn Flutter and have started the Udemy course: https://www.udemy.com/course/flutters-beginners-course/ . In describing Flutter setup Android Studio and IntelliJ is referred to. I'm don't understand why two IDE's are required. Shouldn't either Android Studio or IntelliJ be utilised ? Are both IDE's - Android Studio and IntelliJ required for flutter development ?

Comment: The question title is misleading about your actual inquiry. Please, improve it.

Answer (score 0):

No their not, there is just nice integrations and plugins for both those IDE.

I personally use VSCode.
The only requiered item needed is the Flutter SDK

Answer (score 0):

You don´t need two. I use VScode (https://code.visualstudio.com/Download), but theoretically you can use any other IDE. With Android Studio you have a few more options when it comes to the emulator. I would however recommend VScode or IntelliJ